# Diferença de horas em unidades

Tags: php

Neste momento tenho a diferença de horas a funcionar mas como tenho faz a diferença em horas, ou seja, das 11:00 às 12:30 a diferença é de 1:30h e eu insiro 1.30, mas queria que ele inserisse 1.50.

Quero a diferença de horas em unidades, não em horas.

```
$inicio = new DateTime($horai);
$fim = new DateTime($horaf);

$intervalo = $inicio->diff($fim);
$dhora = $intervalo->format('%H.%i');
```

Comment: Quer 'arredondar' a diferença para cima? qual é o criterio?

Comment: Só quero a diferença das horas em unidades.

Comment: Não tem parâmetro para formatar nessa forma. Pega a diferença dos minutos e divide por 60. Depois adiciona a diferença de horas

Comment: Por que 1.50 se o correto é 1.30, você quer adicionar mais 20 minutos? Se você quer a diferença em minutos, basta converter as horas em minutos e somar com os 30 minutos. Se quer a diferença em horas, pega o valor dos minutos e divide por 60 e soma às horas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem parâmetro para formatar nessa forma. Pega a diferença dos minutos e divide por 60. Depois adiciona a diferença de horas

```
<?php

$inicio = new DateTime("10:00");
$fim = new DateTime("11:30");

$intervalo = $inicio->diff($fim);
$dhora = $intervalo->format('%h.%i');
list($h, $hm) = explode(".", $dhora);

echo $h + ($hm/60);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, estive a tentar e faltou-se a parte do list e do explode.